# Embed logo in antmedia live stream via canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, webrtc, ant-media-server-sdk

Am following the blog at https://antmedia.io/how-to-merge-live-stream-and-canvas-in-webrtc-easily/ that explains how to embed a logo in antmedia live stream. However, I couldn't quite figure out to initialise a localStream with javascript SDK as illustrated in the blog. Specifically, where is the implementation of initWebRTCAdaptor():

```
     //initialize the webRTCAdaptor with the localStream created.

     //initWebRTCAdaptor method is implemented below

     initWebRTCAdaptor(localStream);
```

A complete working sample would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that blog post is not fully up to date.
Let me share what to do to have this feature.

Just add a `localStream` parameter to the `WebRTCAdaptor` constructor.
Secondly, use the below code in place of `initWebRTCAdaptor`

For the full code, please take a look at this gist.
https://gist.github.com/mekya/d7d21f78e7ecb2c34d89bd6ec5bf5799

Make sure that you use your own image in image.src.(Use local images)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var vid = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    var image=new Image();

    image.src="images/play.png";

    function draw() {
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 200, 150);
            ctx.drawImage(image,50, 10, 100, 30);
        }
    }


    setInterval(function() { draw(); }, 50);
    //capture stream from canvas
    var localStream = canvas.captureStream(25);
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}).then(function (stream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('video#localVideo');

        video.srcObject = stream;

        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
            video.play();
        };

    //initialize the webRTCAdaptor with the localStream created.

    //initWebRTCAdaptor method is implemented below

    localStream.addTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

    initWebRTCAdaptor(false, autoRepublishEnabled);
  });
```